# Event control in delay differential equations

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, numerics, event-detection

A delay-differential system for variables {y[t],z[t]} is defined by time-lag w

```
{y'[t] == (r (1 - y[t] - z[t]) - 1) y[t], 
 z'[t] == (y[t] - y[t - w])};
```

The important constraint is 0<z[t]<1. When z crosses 0, the lagged term y[t-w] should be switched off. I tried WhenEvent with discrete 'switch' variable c[t]->0, and 'switch timing' Tc[t] =(t+w),
to prevent z-decay, when z becomes negative. So after time Tc, the 'switch' on the loss term  -y[t-w] could be turned on (c[t]->1)

(*case r=1.2; w=20*)

```
 Ys = NDSolveValue[
      {{Derivative[1][y][t] == y[t] (-1 + 1.2` (1 - y[t] - z[t])),
        Derivative[1][z][t] == -c[t] y[-20 + t] + y[t]},
       {y[t /; t < 0], z[t /; t < 0]} == {.01, 0}, c[0] == 1, Tc[0] == 0,
       WhenEvent[t > 0 && z[t] == 0, {c[t] -> 0, Tc[t] -> t + 20}],
       WhenEvent[t == Tc[t], c[t] -> 1]},
      {x@t, y@t, z@t}, {t, 0, t1 = 100},
       DiscreteVariables -> {c, Tc}]
```

The code run, but ignored all event controls, and produce unphysical solution with z[t] crossing into negative range.
Any suggestions welcome.

P.S. The system formulated in integro-differential form:

```
y'[t] == (r (1 - y[t] - z[t]) - 1) y[t]
z[t]=Integrate[y[s],{s,t-w,t}]
```

But I don't know if that would make it more tractable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The principal error raised in the question can be eliminated by deleting `t > 0` from the first `WhenEvent`.  This probably is related to the first example under *Possible Issues* in the `WhenEvent` documentation.  There are, however, a few other issues that should be addressed:

- `y` and `z` are defined for `t < 0`, whereas `c` and `Tc` are not.  This produces a warning message when the code is run.
- `y` and `z` are undefined for `t == 0`.  Mathematica ignores this.
- `z[t] == 0` should be `z[t] < 0`, according to the documentation.
- `x@t` is undefined.

With these changes, the code is

```
Ys = NDSolveValue[{y'[t] == y[t] (-1 + 6/5 (1 - y[t] - z[t])), 
    z'[t] == -c[t] y[-20 + t] + y[t], y[t /; t <= 0] == 1/100, 
    z[t /; t <= 0] == 0, c[t /; t <= 0] == 1, Tc[t /; t <= 0] == 0, 
    WhenEvent[z[t] < 0, {c[t] -> 0, Tc[t] -> t + 20}], 
    WhenEvent[t > Tc[t], c[t] -> 1]}, {y[t], z[t], c[t], Tc[t]}, 
    {t, 0, 100}, DiscreteVariables -> {c, Tc}];
```

which leads to the results,

```
Plot[{Ys[[1]], Ys[[2]]}, {t, 0, 100}, AxesLabel -> {t, "x,z"}, 
    LabelStyle -> {12, Bold, Black}]
```

[image]

It is prudent, at least initially, to plot `c` and `Tc` as well.

```
Plot[Ys[[3]], {t, 0, 100}, AxesLabel -> {t, c}, LabelStyle -> {12, Bold, Black}]
Plot[Ys[[4]], {t, 0, 100}, AxesLabel -> {t, Tc}, LabelStyle -> {12, Bold, Black}]
```

[image]

[image]

These seem consistent with the desired behavior of the two discrete variables as described in the question.

Comment: Thanks, it works nice and does the job. Much appreciated

Comment: I accept the answer